# is it correct to call the mpz_nextprime from the same arguments?

Tags: c++, primes, gmp

Is it correct to give same arguments to const ptr and to ptr?

````
  mpz_class x("7612058254738945");
  mpz_class y("9263591128439081");
  mpz_class z = x * y;
  std::cout << z.get_str() << std::endl;
  mpz_nextprime(z.__get_mp(), z.__get_mp());
  std::cout << z.get_str() << std::endl; ```
````

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Variable-Conventions)

> GMP lets you use the same variable for both input and output in one call.